# Can you assign different sounds to different applications for notifications?

Tags: sound, notification

I'm using 18.0.4.3 and am hearing notification sounds but don't know which application they are coming from because it's the same sound for all apps.  There don't seem to be badges available for apps like Slack that would make it easier to see if I have received a message.  I'm wondering if its at all possible to assign a different sound for each application that makes a sound for its notification setting?  That would be much easier to know which app is making a notification sound.